# Unable to capture the exception in response of an API using mockmvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

In my Mockito test class i am able to capture the success response of APi but if my API throw, throw new GeneralException(ex.getMessage()); then it fails to capture this exception in response using mockMvc.

Getting error msg:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is about:blank{400, Bad Request, Invalid Parameter, message=error.http.400} at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)

But positive case are running successfully. Only Problem comes with throw new GeneralException(ex.getMessage()); we are using org.zalando.problem dependecy in our project and GenaralException is comes from the same

this is my controller class

```
@PostMapping("/eim/metadata/featureData")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveFeatureData(@RequestBody DcpDTO dcp) {

        String errMsg = ResourceUtil.validateRequest(dcp);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(errMsg)) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException(errMsg);
        }
        if (! this.dcpCommitService.getDcpByName(dcp.getDcpName()).isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException(String.format("Dcp with name [%s] already exists. Name should be unique.", dcp.getDcpName()));
        }

        DcpJobData featureData = null;
        try
        {
            featureData = dcpCommitService.savefeatureData(dcp);
            dcpCommitService.triggerSparkJob(featureData);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {
            log.warn("savefeatureData - Failed to create resource. {}",ex.getMessage());
            throw new BadRequestAlertException(String.format("Failed to create resource. {%s}", ex.getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("savefeatureData - Unexpected error. ", ex);
            throw new GeneralException(String.format("Create operation failed. %s", ex.getMessage()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(featureData, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

My Junit test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ChamberResourceTest {
   
    @InjectMocks
    ChamberResource chamberResource;

    @Mock
    ToolService toolService;

    @Mock
    ChamberService chamberService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ToolList toolList;

    private SiteDetail siteDetail;
    private CustomerDetail customerDetail;
    private ChamberList chamberList;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(chamberResource).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void test_BadRequest() throws Exception {
        when(chamberService.getChamberListByTool(anyList())).thenThrow(BadRequestAlertException.class);
        DcpDTO dcpDTO = new DcpDTO();
        dcpDTO.setCustomerUUID(UUID.fromString("9e94a351-b2b8-4c36-8a9a-6828f1e9932f"));
        dcpDTO.setFleetUUID(UUID.fromString("c69a82c6-55bf-437a-b265-f519aafebf15"));
        dcpDTO.setChamberUUIDs(Arrays.asList("dadc3fd7-90a4-4fc1-9813-b2d99e27bc2b", "fcdf0f3c-6874-480f-9f18-107177176fa6"));
        dcpDTO.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-06-30T17:23:22"));
        dcpDTO.setEndTime(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-06-30T16:42:22"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()  );
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dcpDTO);
        restUserMockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/eim/metadata/featureData")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic cmFpYXY6UGFydGhAMDY=")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(jsonString))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

if i run my junit test i am getting below error message

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is about:blank{400, Bad Request, Invalid Parameter, message=error.http.400}    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)

same type of errror message i am getting if i mock InternalServerError and in mockMVC i expect it gives InternalServerError ,

```
 restUserMockMvc
            .perform(get("/eim/metadata/featureData")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
```

but not able to capture the responce using mockmvc..getting below errro
for the same type of errro i am getting if API that throgh GenaralException:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is about:blank{500, Internal Server Error, message=error.codeException}

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you have no error handler setup. [here is a baeldung explanation](https://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20BadRequestAlertException(String.format(%22Failed%20to%20create%20resource.%20%7B%25s%7D%22,%20ex.getMessage()));)

The issue here is that you are throwing, but not catching the exception and converting it to a response code:

One solution is to setup such an error handler. Another solution would be to also return response entities for errors:

```
    try
    {
        featureData = dcpCommitService.savefeatureData(dcp);
        dcpCommitService.triggerSparkJob(featureData);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
    {
        log.warn("savefeatureData - Failed to create resource. {}",ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>("abc", HttpStatus.ERROR);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("savefeatureData - Unexpected error. ", ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("abc2", HttpStatus.ERROR);
    }
```